# Current Encryption Algorithms?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, algorithm

What are some encryption algorithms that are currently in use by secure websites, by operating systems, or by Secure USB thumb drive manufacturers. I am trying to do research on differences in speed on algorithms that are currently used. I know security is a debatable factor, but I am not concerned with that. I just want to know what some of the common algorithms that are used today are.

Comment: Symmetric encryption: AES is the big one, RC4 and 3DES are legacy. A few choose alternatives like TwoFish, Serpent, ChaCha/Salsa20. We might get a few other nice choices out of the CAESAR competition. Asymmetric encryption: RSA, (elliptic curve) Diffie-Hellman plus something symmetric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common block encryption algorithms:

- AES (Rijndael)
- Blowfish
- DES (Data Encryption Standard)
- Triple DES
- Serpent
- Twofish
- Camellia
- CAST
- IDEA

Common stream encryption algorithms:

- RC4

Common cryptographic hash functions:

- MD5
- SHA-1
- SHA-2
- SHA-3 (Keccak)
- HAVAL
- RIPEMD
- Tiger
- WHIRLPOOL

In the public key cryptography realm, we have:

- DSA (Digital Signature Algorithm)
- RSA (Rivest-Shamir-Adleman)
- ECDH (elliptic curve Diffie–Hellman)
- ECDSA (Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm)

All of these algorithms are commonly used and have been around for some time.

As for speed, all of them are really implementation-dependent and each implementation will be subjected to the environment they're used in. Hardware-implemented algorithms are obviously going to be the fastest. Intel, for example, has implemented AES-NI in their processors for accelerating AES encryption with throughput measured in gigabytes per second, but the actual throughput depends on other factors like storage speed and network throughput.